# PHP + Apache : Universal way to get the application base URL path

Tags: php, apache

I'm developing a PHP app with the following structure:

```
my-app/
  WEB/
    css/
    images/
    javascript/
    index.php
    .htaccess
  lib/
    my-app/
      ...
    config.php
```

The web server is pointed to the `WEB` directory and `lib` is in PHP's `include_path`.
`mod_rewrite` is used to rewrite requests to missing files to `index.php`, which loads a `RequestDispatcher` class from `lib` to do the processing.

In previous apps I've been using a configuration file which stores the **application base URL path**, e.g.: `/my-app` .

Now I'm developing a web app which should be available at multiple URL paths at the same time from one codebase - e.g. in `/usr/share/my-app` and multiple domains can use it from there and map it to freely choosen path by e.g. symlinking, `Alias`-ing, etc .

There are multiple propsed solutions on the net, including this site, but none of the ones I've found works reliably.

The proposed solution should work in all PHP web execution environments:

- mod_php
- FPM
- Fast CGI
- other ?

when the URL path mapping is done via:

- direct installation in a web server public directory - e.g. `DocumentRoot /usr/share/my-app/WEB`, path: **''**
- symlinking - `DOCROOT/my-app -> /usr/share/my-app/WEB`, path: **/my-app**
- `Alias`-ing - `Alias /my-app/ /usr/share/my-app/WEB/`, path: **/my-app**
- `mod_userdir` - `/home/USER/public-html/my-app -> /usr/share/my-app/WEB`, path: **/~USER/my-app**
- other ?

I've developed the following:

```
$app_base_url_path = str_replace( '/' . \basename(__FILE__), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
```

which, when put in `WEB/index.php`, works in common cases but still has some issues in some of the tested scenarios. E.g:

- when DOCROOT is pointed to `/home/USER/public_html`( where `mod_userdir` is also pointed to ) and he app is accessed as `/~USER/my-app/`, the path is returned as just `/my-app` (where its also available BTW), which is incorrect and can cause problems when used for e.g. a COOKIE path. This might be Apache HTTPd bug though, as `$_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX']` is empty, while it should be `/~USER` IMHO.

My tests were done with PHP 7.3 running as mod_php on Apache 2.4.38 on Debian 10 (Buster).

P.S. I'm also interested in results in different environments(including other web servers), espesially ones which are not too common. If you find this working or not please post a comment with your environment details and results.

Comment: Well, `basename(__FILE__)` can be replaced with `__DIR__` for simplicity's sake.

Comment: It can't because it takes the filename, not the path.

Comment: [__DIR__](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php): The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

Comment: I think you are trying too hard to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  Your PHP shouldn't care where it is running by using relative paths.  The path inside of index.php is always going to need to know where lib is, ie a relative or absolute path.  You can put lib in php's path, and thus include it as if it were relative to index.php. Other options include using an env variable but the php path is really there to solve this specific issue.

Comment: The php.ini setting you want is `include_path`